# The type initializer threw an exception for assemblies in 64 bit OS

Tags: 64-bit, gac

I am using [Sage](http://www.sage.co.uk/sage-200) Assemblies in my Visual Studio 2008 project. **But when the project is deployed in a 64 bit OS, it crashes with type initializer exception**. I tried setting the `Copy Local = false` so that assemblies from the target PC's GAC would be used.

For the record, I also navigated to the GAC directory of the target PC and the `Processor Architecture = x86` for the assemblies for which I am getting exception. Also running `corsflag` shows the assemblies are 32 bit.

*Does that the mean the assemblies have to be MSIL or x64 to work in 64 bit OS?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got my answers and it is not required for assemblies to be x64 or MSIL to work on 64 bit OSs. All I had to do was build my setup project against the architecture of the assemblies which was 32 bit.